# How to find all perfect squares in a given range of numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I need to write a program that finds all perfect squares between two given numbers a and b such that the range can also be a = 1 and b = 10^15 what is the best way I can do this, how do I list down all such square numbers, is there some abstract math hidden underneath this problem?

Comment: How about n = int( sqrt(b) ) - int( sqrt(a) ) ?

Comment: @JakubCzaplicki Thanks, it's working fine but can you explain it more? how it works from the inside?

Comment: @Menaim Take 1,2,3,4,5,6,.. and then take exponent of 2 of those numbers: 1,4,9,16,25,36,etc. Notice that the number of perfect squares between two given numbers, is the same number as the number of numbers between the sqrt of the two. There are 5 numbers between 6 and 1, and so there are 5 perfect squares between 36 and 1. That's it. You just need to round down the sqrt (this I am not 100% sure, but seems to be good enough approach).

Comment: Thanks @JakubCzaplicki

Comment: You should make this an actual answer @JakubCzaplicki.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One thing that makes this pretty straight forward is this: $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$ Start with one, and keep on adding that.

Comment: what has this formula to do with the problem?

Comment: What I said... You can start with $a$ and keep on applying the formula to obtain all of the squares, one after the next

Comment: You can start with $1$, then add $2 * 1 + 1 = 3$ to it and get $4$, then add $2 * 2 + 1 = 5$ to it and get $9$, and so forth.

btw, $10^{15}$ is outside of the "int" range so I would suggest using "long".

Comment: I don't understand the part keep on applying the formula, what does that mean can you show by an example and because there might be overflow on the computer how to remedy that?

Comment: 1,4,9. Their differences are 3,5 or 2*1+1, 2*2+1

Comment: To avoid overflow, I would sugust following 2012's advice

Comment: I am using unsigned long long to avoid overflow but the output does overflow :(

Comment: @AnkitSablok: using $64$-bit integers, this is not surprising since this will only allow numbers up to $2^{64}\approx 10^{18}$.  You might consider using a BigInt library of some sort.  There are some standard ones available for most programming languages.

Comment: What about -ve numbers range E.g(-100, 100)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it much easily by first calculating the square roots of $a$ and $b$. And count the number of integers between those square roots (just subtract one from the other). But be careful when one of $a$ and $b$ is a square itself.

Comment: Also, watch out for the case where a == b

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code (pretty much C/C++) to implement Chris Dugale's answer:

```
long i = 1;
for (long n = i*i; i < k; i++) {
  n += 2i + 1;
  printf("%l\n", n);
}
```

The idea is that $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1$, so to get $(n+1)^2$ from $n^2$, just add $2n+1$ to it.  Then, to get $(n+2)^2$ from $(n+1)^2$ you add $2n+3$, and so on...

Comment: what should the value of k be if I need to find all the perfect squares between a = 20 b = 10^6 ? how do you decide that

Comment: That's an unusual set of limits, but then you would say $n=20,i=20,k=10^3=1000.$

Comment: I don't get how are you deciding the value of k and n, in general if you want to find the square numbers between [a,b] how does one go about it using the snippet you provided, I executed the snippet but it yields wrong result for a = 1 and b = 10 and a= 100 and b = 10000

Comment: My bad, I should have said $n=25,i=5$ as the first square inside the range.  For $a=1$ you would have $n=1,i=1$ and for $a=100$ you would have $n=100,i=10$.  For the $b$ values, I picked the largest integer less than or equal to the square root, so for $b=10,k=3$ and for $b=10000,k=100$.  I have updated the C-ish code in my answer to have $n$ begin at the correct point.