# Explicit formula for a recurrance relationship $A_n = A_{n-1} + 2n + 1$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursion, square-numbers

$$a_n = a_{n-1} + 2n + 1 $$
$$ a_0 = 1 $$
$$ a_1 = 4 $$
$$ a_2 = 9 $$

I know the basics of how to use characteristic polynomials, but I'm not sure how the $2n$ would be represented in the characteristic polynomial.

Essentially, the question I'm working on trying to answer is being able to generate all perfect squares within a range [A-B] efficiently, and I saw this recurrence relationship. Any help on how to turn this into an explicit formula? Or how else to tackle this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: $A_n-A_{n-1}$ is linear, so $A_n$ is quadratic. Initial conditions yield $a_n=(n-1)^2$ - perfect squares as expected.

Comment: Odd: to see that $a_0=1$, $a_1=4$, $a_2=9$, raised no idea of a conjecture about what the value of $a_n$ for every $n$ could be?

Comment: Ohhh. I see. So, for finding all perfect squares in [A-B] you can set $A_n = A$ solve for n, then recurse until $A_n >= B$

Comment: @Did: I think OP sees that squares are generated, but wants to turn this into an algorithm. ¶ Also, by the way, in A.S.'s comment, $a_n = (n+1)^2$, not $(n-1)^2$.

Comment: @BrianTung Maybe this is so, maybe not (I mean, the first part of your comment, since the second part is unequivocally true). Actually, it is difficult to know what the question really is.

Comment: This is somewhat similar:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548043/how-to-find-all-perfect-squares-in-a-given-range-of-numbers

Comment: Use telescoping sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$a_{n}-a_{n-1}=2n+1$$

Take the sum of both sides from $n=1$ to $n=x$, looks to me like a telescoping series on the left.

If you go through the telescoping sum process you will see:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{x} (a_{n}-a_{n-1})= a_x-a_0=a_x-1$$

Now can you take the right hand sum, and equate your two results?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *exactly* sure what it is you're looking for, but you might proceed, in pseudocode, as follows:

```
k = ceil(sqrt(A))
Sk = k^2
while (Sk <= B) {
    output Sk
    Sk = Sk+2k+1
    k = k+1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a_n-a_{n-1}=2n-1$ implies $a_n-a_0=\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=n^2.$