# How do I find a formula to find the even squares between two numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a coding assignment where I have to take two numbers, and print all the even square numbers between them.

like this:

(1, 100)

4, 16, 36, 64, 100

I want to find a math formula to do this. I have tried looking on other threads, but they were poorly explained or the solutions didn't work like this thread: [How to find all perfect squares in a given range of numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548043/how-to-find-all-perfect-squares-in-a-given-range-of-numbers?newreg=f4935201670a4485b6b81fcd70252843)

How do I find this? No code please.

Comment: If $A$ is the first number just take the square root of $\frac A4$ and round up and call it $n$ and if $B$ is the second number just take the square root of $\frac B4$ and round down and call it $m$.  Then the even perfect squares between $A$ and $B$ will be $4n^2, 4(n+1)^2,  ....., 4(m-1)^2, 4m^2$.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say you have to find all even squares between integers $a$ and $b$ (included), with $a \le b$, i.e. all even squares in $[a,b]$. I'll use informal English rather than math notation, in case you are not familiar with math notation. In case you prefer to have math notation, please tell.

Take:
$c =$ integer part of $\sqrt a$
$d =$ lowest even integer greater than or equal to $c$
Test if $d^2 = a$. If this is the case, $d^2$ is your first result number.
In all cases, increase $d$ by $2$.
Test whether the new $d^2$ is lower or equal to $b$. If true, this is a new result number.
Loop until $d^2 > b$.

Example: all even squares between 50 and 150, included.
$c =$ integer part of $\sqrt {50}$ $= 7$
$d=8$
$d^2$ is greater than $50$ so we test whether $d^2$ is lower or equal to $150$. This is the case, so $8^2 = 64$ is the first number we want.
Then we increase $d$ by $2$ which gives $10$.
$10^2 = 100$ which is lower or equal to $150$ so that is the second number we want.
Then $12^2 = 144$ is accepted too.
The next one is $14^2 = 196$ which is greater than $150$ so we stop at $144$.

As a variant, you may notice that the sequence of even $d^2$ increases by $12, 20, 28, 36$ etc.: the difference is a sequence that increases $8$ by $8$.
This is because $(2n+2)^2 - (2n)^2 = 8n + 4$.
So when you take $d =$ lowest even integer greater than or equal to $c$, compute $d^2$, then to get the next $d^2$ increase by $4d+4$.

Example: above we had the first accepted number $8^2 = 64$. So $d=8$. Add $4d+4 = 36$ to $64$, that gives $100$ which is also accepted.
Then add $4 \times 10 + 4 = 44$ to $100$, that is $144$, accepted also.
Then add $4 \times 12 + 4 = 52$ to $144$, that is $196$, greater than $150$ so we stop at the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have $(A,B)$ and you want to find all the even squares between $A, B$.

Well, just do it.

If $0\le A \le n^2 \le B$ and $n^2$ is even, then $n$ is even.  So let $n=2m$.  Then $n^2 = (2m)^2 = 4m$ so $0\le A \le 4m^2 \le B$.

That means $\frac A4 \le m^2 \le \frac B4$ and that $\sqrt{\frac A4} \le m \le \sqrt{\frac B4}$.

So just find all the integers, $m$, between $\sqrt{\frac A4}$ and $\sqrt{\frac B4}$ and square them and multiply by $4$ to get all the even squares.

For example: if you want to find all the even squares between $101$ and $4087$ we take $L = \sqrt{\frac {101}4} =\sqrt{25.25}\approx 5.0249$ and we take $U = \sqrt{\frac {4087}4}=\sqrt{1021.75} \approx 31.965$.

Now we just take all the integers between $5.0249$ and $31.965$, that is,  $6,7,8,9,10,11,........,28, 29, 30, 31$ and we square them to get $36, 49, ......, 841,900, 961$ and we multiply them by $4$ to get $144, 196, ....., 3364, 3600, 3844$.

And that's that.  That is all the even squares between $101$ and $4087$.